# Turning post request data into .each() function

Tags: javascript, arrays, each

I'm using this code

```
$.post("assets/scripts/chat/load_convos.php",{}, function(data) {
$.each(data, function(index, value) { 
  alert(value);
});
```

,and the return of the `data` is `[57,49]` but it just doesn't do anything... If I replace the `data` just after the `$.each(` with `[57,49]` it works but not with the `data` in its place.

I'm not the best with Javascript so all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with "the `data` is `[57,49]`" ?

My guess is, that you expect a (JSON)-object but you just receive a string. My second guess is that jQuery interpretates the result the wrong way and does not identify the return as JSON-String and hence, does not implicit `JSON.parse` it.

Check the content-types of the request. Try to call `data = JSON.parse(data);` manually before calling the `each` loop. Actually jQuery should be able to identiy that string as a JSON result itself, so I'm also wondering which jQuery version you use.

Another shot you might have is to call `.getJSON()` instead of `.post()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse` or `eval('('+response+')');` but probably the solution is to specify to jQuery or the library you are using that the response is JSON.

By the way, no all browsers have the JSON object, so if your library don't provide it you'll have to use the eval solution.

Answer (score 0):

Specify json as your datatype.

[Taken from jquery.post documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
Example: Posts to the test.php page and gets contents which has been 
         returned in json format 
(<;?php echo json_encode(array("name"=>"John","time"=>"2pm")); ?>).
$.post("test.php", { "func": "getNameAndTime" },
    function(data){
        console.log(data.name); // John
        console.log(data.time); //  2pm
    }, "json");
```